# users can't receive notification on updating the app

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

By mistake, I uploaded the **GoogleService-info.plist** from some other project with different bundle identifier in my latest release, to my AppStore. and now many people have downloaded the application from this release, and obviously they're not receiving any remote notifications. Now when I changed the **GoogleService-info.plist** to the actual project file and uploaded the app to test flight, when I update the app I still don't receive any notifications but when I uninstall and reinstall the app I start getting notifications. however, there're many users who are already using the app and now they'll just update the app and not re-install.
any help in this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: strange problem. The updated with the correct google.plist should be pushed to their devices once they update. Same with the one that you updated to TestFlight. Possibly you're doing something else wrong?

Comment: what could be the possible mistake? I've tried many things... its working fine when uninstalling and installing the app, but not on updating.

Comment: Did you contact Apple support?

Comment: I just read your answer I will contact them tomorrow. Thankyou..

Comment: np. Please update the post when they fix it. Good luck!

Comment: if wish this dude let us know what happened. he basically just left everyone hanging. :(

Comment: brother I was actually unable to solve this, so what happened only the users that have downloaded the app with wrong file they would need to uninstall and re-install the app to get the notifications, and for all the new users it was working fine.
But what's the confusing part is I had mistakenly did the same thing in another application too but on that i just removed the wrong GoogleService file and replace it with the right one and release the app, and it was working for the old users too, i know its strange but i couldn't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is an unusual problem. The binary that you upload should have the new plist along with it. At this point you should contact apple developer support. I've had problems and they were very helpful.

1- Log in to AppStoreConnect

2- They changed things around. Go to the lower right hand corner and select Contact Us

[image]

3- If you select `Development and Technical` all the options from there will give you **email** support only. If you want phone support select `Membership and Account` > `Account Access` and from there you will get the choice of **phone** or **email** support.

I haven't spoken to them in a while but the problem that I had the initial operator couldn't help me and she had a specialist reach out to me. After I spoke to him he couldn't figure out how to fix the issue. He asked a supervisor and the supervisor couldn't figure it out. He said it was his first time experiencing such an issue (I had a regular account, expired paid account, and an active paid account, and one of my app bundle identifiers were still with the expired account but I needed it on my active account -it was headache). I had to send him an email detailing all the steps that led up to the problem and everything that I tried to do to fix it. They sent that email to a special team above them. **Have an email like that already prepared**.

It took a couple of days but the team figured out the issue just based off of the everything that he documented and tried and the detailed email that I sent them. The response 100% fixed the issue.

I have plenty of gripes with their app review team but apple's tech support, from what I've seen so far is top notch and very responsive.

If they fix the issue please come back here and add an update so that if someone else has this problem they can use it as a reference.